# Is there a pattern for having a differing number of Input/Output, but the same core responsibility of work?

Tags: java, design-patterns, abstract-class, abstraction

There is a pattern in my codebase that looks a lot like this: We are processing messages from a queue and then passing that message along to the next queue. The use case up until now has been that we process and produce the same type of message.

```
public interface Processor<T> {
  T process(T thing);
}
```

That use case has evolved to processing and producing a different type. In addition, we may need to process one type and produce a series of others.

So something like:

```
public interface NewProcessor<I, O> {
  O process(I thing;)
}
```

and in the future will likely need something like

```
public interface FutureProcessor<I, O1, O2> { //potentially N number of O
  Pair<O1, O2> process(I thing);
}
```

My question is: Is there a way to express this cleaner than having three separate classes? Is there a nice known hierarchy I could use here?

We have an abstract user of the first type of processor that I would prefer to not have to re-write every time we add a new processor. It does something like this today:

```
public abstract AbstractModule<T> {
  private Processor<T> processor;
  public AbstractModule(Processor<T> processor) {
   this.processor = processor;
  }

  T runModule(T input) {
    // abstract validateInput(input);
    T result = processor.process();
    // record results
    return result;
  }
}
```

Any known patterns or suggestions on how to do this would be appreciated!

Comment: The problem statement is very abstract. In general, if you have different processing outputs, you'll need different handling mechanisms. But perhaps with more detail about the specific inputs and outputs, a more concrete answer is possible.

Comment: We are processing messages from a queue and then passing that message along to the next queue. The use case up until now has been that we process and produce the same type of message. That use case has evolved to processing and producing a different type. In addition, we may need to process one type and produce a series of others. Will update the question with this.

Comment: It seems like the `processor` should be accepting `input` inside `runModule(...)` based on the interface declaration.

Answer (score 4):

Your use case is getting an object, doing something with it and generating a new one. Basically a function of one argument. The critical part I think is the amount of arguments because you can only return one result in Java. If you are sure you won't need to process more than one object at a time in the future then there is no more generic way to do that that using a function like the one you have already defined (I would use the JDK ones when possible though, in this case [`Function`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html) and [`UnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/UnaryOperator.html)).

Let's say you want to keep using your custom functions and you don't want to change your `AbstractModule` as you said. I would rename `Processor` as `UnaryProcessor` at least. Then I would change it as follows:

```
public interface Processor<T, R> {
    R process(T t);
}
```

---

```
public interface UnaryProcessor<T> extends Processor<T, T> {}
```

At this point you will be able to handle the last use case you mentioned as `Processor<T, Pair<O1, O2>>`. The same logic would apply to any future use case, you just need to replace the return type by any type you need at that moment, for example a `List<E>`.

Comment: It seems like the crux of the question is that the processes are *not* functions: they have multiple outputs for a given input. A `Pair` result is already in use, but it doesn't scale well to higher numbers of results, and a different approach is sought.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning results from the method call, initialize each processor with callbacks for each result it may generate from an input.

This is well-suited for a queue-processing application, since the callback might produce a new message for a different queue, and you can intercept the result easily to do things like monitoring without modifying the processor.

```
interface Processor<T> {
  void process(T message);
}

interface Output<T> {
  result(T result);
}

class SomeKindOfProcessor implements Processor<SomeInput> {

  private final Output<? super Foo> foo;
  private final Output<? super Bar> bar;

  // These parameters are probably injected by some sort of IoC container.
  // They are easy to mock in tests too, so you can unit test this
  // class in isolation.
  SomeKindOfProcessor(Output<? super Foo> foo, Output<? super Bar> bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  @Override
  public void process(SomeInput input) {
     /* Do some work that results in a Bar instance */
     bar.result(new Bar(...));
     /* Do some more work that might result in a Foo instance. */
     if (...) {
        foo.result(new Foo(...));
     }
  }

}
```

If the callback implementation needs to correlate results with the input, you can generally use some identifier from the input to do that.

Answer (score 0):

your output result could be abstract and you always return it

```
class Result<T1, T2, T3>{// only change Result class   
    boolean hasType1     //no need to change method interface that returns Result
    boolean hasType2
    boolean hasType3

    T1 t1
    T2 t2
    T3 t3    
    // you can use other implementation such as array...
}

public interface Processor<T> {//only one interface that always returns Result
  Result process(T thing);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the Processor functional interface take multiple inputs and/or outputs you keep it as is, but instead use an aggregate input and/or output.

You should prefer giving the aggregate a useful name, for a pair of ints may e.g. be called Vertex, Point, Dimensions etc. depending on what those ints represents. Only if there is no useful name for your aggregate and you are not to use it elsewhere is it a good idea to use a generic such as ProcessInput or ProcessOutput.

Example of aggreget:

```java
class Vertex {
   final public int x;
   final public int y;

   public Vertex(int x, int y) {
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
   }
}
```

I usually prefer keeping the fields in such an aggregate final making the time immutable, but there is nothing that require you to do so.

It is like some other have suggested possible to create a generic aggregate. Don't think you need to do this. I usually prefer aggregates with god useful names and where individual member fields or properties can also have good useful names. Having to remember that the third integer is the count or the second String is the name can lead to the code not being as easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could apply something like the *decorator pattern*. This will allow you to have one interface, let's say `java.util.Function`, but easily introduce intermediate conversion steps for your inputs and outputs.

```
class Decorator<I, O, D> implements Function<I, D>
{
    private final Function<I, O> function;
    private final Function<O, D> delegate;

    public Decorator( Function<I , O> function, Function<O, D> delegate )
    {
        this.function = function;
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }

    @Override
    public D apply( I input )
    {
        O output = function.apply( input );
        return delegate.apply( output );
    }
}
```

Here's a simple example converting strings to integers, modifying the string, and then converting back to integer:

```
@Test
public void testDelegate()
{
    Function<Integer, String> intToString = String::valueOf;

    Decorator<Integer, String, String> repeatString = new Decorator<>(
            intToString, s -> s + s );

    assertEquals( "33", repeatString.apply( 3 ));

    Decorator<Integer, String, Integer> repeatThenToInt = new Decorator<>(
            repeatString, Integer::valueOf );

    assertEquals( 33, repeatThenToInt.apply( 3 ).intValue() );
}
```